# Can't read php on server

Tags: php

I trying to read php file on server, in android.

Sorry for shot english because i am foreigner..

```
   <html>
     <head>
      <title>aaa</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text" charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
        $link_id = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db('aaaa',$link_id);

        $res = mysql_query("insert into ppt_member value ('$id','$password','$name','$email','$address','$sex','$age')",$link_id);

    ?>
```

this is my php code.

When i run application,

```
07-22 01:41:32.505: W/Response(1195): <html>
07-22 01:41:32.505: W/Response(1195):  <head>
07-22 01:41:32.505: W/Response(1195):   <title>aaa</title>
07-22 01:41:32.505: W/Response(1195): <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text" charset="utf-8">
07-22 01:41:32.505: W/Response(1195): </head>
07-22 01:41:32.505: W/Response(1195): <body>
07-22 01:41:32.505: W/Response(1195):
```

Can read until html code, but can't read php code.

What should i do?

Comment: do you have display_errors enabled in php.ini? http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: Do you mean that you expect to see the *actual PHP code* in the HTTP response?  That *shouldn't* happen.  The PHP code should execute server-side and all any client should see is the resulting response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a server that runs PHP, all `*.php` files are executed by the server when requested. PHP is executed on the server **BEFORE** the HTTP response is sent to the client. This means that the PHP code will never be visible to the client. You'll have to use FTP to download the files themselves in order to see the code.

You can make your results visible by `echo`ing them or `print`ing them such as in:

```
<?php
        $link_id = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        mysql_select_db('aaaa',$link_id);

        $res = mysql_query("insert into ppt_member value ('$id','$password','$name','$email','$address','$sex','$age')",$link_id);

        echo ($res ? 'Insert Success' : 'Insert Failed'); // look here
    ?>
```

Which will print 'Insert Success' if the query was successful and 'Insert Failed' otherwise..

Answer (score 3):

You can’t read the contents of a PHP script, as the script is executed by the server and the result then sent.

If you could read the contents of PHP scripts from an external source, then imagine the damage someone could do—they could get database passwords and other configuration variables and just see how your website/application works in general.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see the output after the HTML is that te php code you have shown doesn't Generate any output.  You would need to iterate and echo $res to see Something